# How to image dim jssor partial visible slider

Tags: jquery, slider, jssor

I use **[Jssor Slider](http://www.jssor.com/demos/nearby-image-partial-visible-slider.html)** and I want to dim/overlay/fade out next and previous image this way:

[image]

Is there a way I can add CSS class to those two slides on slide transition (and remove on others)?

Comment: Wanted to guide people to the correct answer. There are two ways to solve this: to add/remove class or to directly style elements.

Comment: @skobaljic: i tried add class for images but not working...  cant apply directly style elements for div or images..

Comment: You can see in [this thread](https://github.com/jssor/slider/issues/38) how to bind events. There you get active index, that is enough to add/remove styles.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this would be possible since jssor does not use any css classes to identify which slide is currently in the center and which ones are besides it. However, I created a plugin that was not as complicated as Jssor. It has options to dim the side images with black translucent background but you can easily edit the css to use white there. You can check the plugin here: [partialViewSlider](https://github.com/VeeK727/partialViewSlider/)

Comment: Thank you very much. This plugin https://github.com/VeeK727/partialViewSlider/ is the best, easiest one for those who wants partial visible nearby images in slider.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for your problem. Set image with no-slide attribute (range from 0, 1, ...). So you pick current index and set suitable CSS (opacity...)

```
var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);
        
        jssor_1_slider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, changeSlideEffect);
        
        function changeSlideEffect() {
            var currentIndex = jssor_1_slider.$CurrentIndex();
            $("img[no-slide = " + currentIndex +" ]").css({
                'opacity': 1,
                'transition' : '300ms'
            });
            $("img[no-slide != " + currentIndex +" ]").css({
                'opacity': 0.7,
                'transition' : '300ms'
            });
            
        }
```